# Both keys of touchpad performing the same function after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: touchpad, 18.04

I am using Lenovo Ideapad 320e. After updating to 18.04, both keys of the touchpad  perform the same function.

I am unable to open the dialog box which gets opened by putting the mouse pointer at proper place and pressing right key of the touchpad.

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on my Dell Inspiron 5565 running Ubuntu 18.04. I solved it by installing GNOME Tweaks via Ubuntu Software. 
I then changed the setting under "Mouse Click Emulation" to area. I had to restart for the change to take effect. Just logging out didn't do it for some reason. Here is a pic. of the tool. 
[image]